# Command FOR EACH ROW in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop-1.6

Help me please.I want to create trigger in mysql server but server wrote me

SQL query: Documentation

```
CREATE TRIGGER `dis_out_of_stock` AFTER UPDATE ON `ps_stock_available`
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
UPDATE `ps_product_shop` SET active=0 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT 
id_product FROM `ps_stock_available` WHERE quantity=0);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Here is my code:

1. CREATE TRIGGER `dis_out_of_stock` AFTER UPDATE ON `ps_stock_available`
2. FOR EACH ROW
3. begin
4. UPDATE `ps_product_shop` SET active=0 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM `ps_stock_available` WHERE quantity=0);
5. UPDATE `ps_product_shop` SET active=1 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM `ps_stock_available` WHERE quantity>0);
6. end

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: You need `END` for every `BEGIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to redefine `DELIMITER` to something else other than `;`, for eg: `$$`
- Also, check if the trigger already exists or not, using `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS`.
- At the end, redefine the `DELIMITER` to `;`

Try:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dis_out_of_stock $$
CREATE TRIGGER dis_out_of_stock 
  AFTER UPDATE ON ps_stock_available 
    FOR EACH ROW begin 

      UPDATE ps_product_shop 
      SET active=0 
      WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product 
                           FROM ps_stock_available 
                           WHERE quantity = 0);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much it`s work but I have 2 condition. One is DISABLE product and second is ENABLE product. I wanted to add AND but not work...

Comment: @PavelMišík what do you mean ? Why it is not working ? Are you receiving any error ?

Comment: @PavelMišík Ok, so you want to disable (`active = 0`) when quantity is 0, and enable (`active = 1`) when quantity > 0 ?

Comment: @PavelMišík try this query:   `UPDATE ps_product_shop AS pps 
      JOIN ps_stock_available AS psa ON psa.id_product = pps.id_product  
      SET pps.active = IF(psa.quantity = 0, 0, 1)`

Comment: Not work....I set quantity to 6 in product options but system not enable product...

Comment: @PavelMišík what is the definition of enable product. It depends on lot of things. also, trigger is on `ps_product_shop` table, while you are updating quantity is `ps_stock_available` table.

Comment: Ouuur sorry...It`s works...When I changed quantity in product from 0 to 6 and puss button Save so function not works but if I open second product and I set quantity so automatically update the quantity without clicking on the Save button to switch products on or off by quantity

Answer (score 0):

You should not be attempting to update the entire `ps_product_shop` table.  Instead, just look at the record that was just modified:

```
DELIMTER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `dis_out_of_stock` AFTER UPDATE ON `ps_stock_available`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE ps_product_shop ps 
        SET active = 0
        WHERE ps.id_product = new.id_product and new.quantity = 0;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: When I used your solution so system write me error but without description, only title Error